# Greedy Vertex Cover on Bipartite Graphs

Tags: sql, algorithm, graph, computer-science

I have the following problem. All suggestions appreciated.

Given a set of questions Q and subjects S, select q questions such that all subjects S are covered. A question might cover multiple subjects.

I built a greedy algorithm over SQL Server. I pick the first question associated with the subject s1 and remove all other subjects that are covered by it. I continue and see if there is a solution.

Here's the catch. Now I want to improve my algorithm and create question sets that are still covering the subjects but are not similar to each other more than 50%.

Any advice on the formal name of this problem. Any algorithms. Should this problem be solved for all sets together, or can it be solved one set at a time.

Comment: Please formalise the definition of *to be similar more than 50%*.

Comment: For any set of questions, S1 and S2, the number of same questions in the sets should not be more than half the set size. The set size is determined by coverage. For 10 questions and 4 subjects, coverage can be reached using say 4 questions. S1 and S2 should not have more than 2 questions common.

Comment: You mentioned two problems. Check topics [set cover](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) and [block design](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design).